IndicesRequest: how to use withJson method in order to sets additional properties to IndicesRequest?
I created an IndicesRequest in Java client elasticsearch 8.
I noticed there is a method co.elastic.clients.json.WithJson.withJso : co.elastic.clients.json.WithJson.withJso in order to append parameters to the request.
I am trying to use that method withJson(Reader input) in order to append "s" parameter for sorting the results by index creation date.
These are all the different options that I tried but nothing worked for me and I am getting the exception: Class class co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.cat.IndicesRequest cannot be read from JSON
    Reader stringReader = new StringReader("{\"s\": \"creation.date.string:desc\"}");
    Reader stringReader2 = new StringReader("\"s=creation.date.string:desc\"");
    Reader stringReader3 = new StringReader("\"&s=creation.date.string:desc\"");
    Reader stringReader4 = new StringReader("&s=creation.date.string:desc");
    Reader stringReader5 = new StringReader("creation.date.string:desc");
    Reader stringReader6 = new StringReader("{\"s\": \"creation.date.string\":\"desc\"}");
    Reader stringReader7 = new StringReader("{\"creation.date.string\":\"desc\"}");
    Reader stringReader8 = new StringReader("{\"s\"= \"creation.date.string\":\"desc\"}");
    

here I sent the different variation of stringReader in order to create the request but got an exception:
    IndicesRequest request = IndicesRequest.of(ir -> ir.index(patterns).withJson(stringReaderX));       

Does anyone tried that API and can help?
